# Вопрос по игре, как сделать так чтобы пули из дробовика вылетали с разбросом?

Tags: алгоритм

Вопрос по игре, как сделать так чтобы пули из дробовика вылетали с разбросом?

Если так то пули сливаются вместе, когда стреляем диагонально,

```
m_bullets.push_back(std::make_shared<CBullet>( sf::Vector2f{ direction.x - 0.05f, direction.y + 0.05f }, ));
m_bullets.push_back(std::make_shared<CBullet> direction));
m_bullets.push_back(std::make_shared<CBullet>(sf::Vector2f{ direction.x + 0.05f, direction.y - 0.05f }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так сойдет?

```
 direction.x*cos(alpha)+direction.y*sin(alpha)
-direction.x*sin(alpha)+direction.y*cos(alpha)
```

и задавать небольшие значения `alpha`. Синус и косинус можно предвычислить.

Comment: сойдет)) спасибо

Comment: Ну, тогда помечайте ответ как принятый :)

Comment: сразу нельзя, через 8 минут

Comment: Да я не настаиваю на срочности :)